# Changing column position in rows

Tags: display-suite, theming

I've this layout:

```
<div class="row1">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" id="col1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" id="col2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" id="col3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="col4"></div>
</div>
```

This is perfect on large-small screen. But not adapt for what i want to displayed on mobile.
Displayed:

col1 col2 **col3**

```
 col4
```

How can i get this: col3 and col4 reodered on mobile. 
Like this:

col1 col2 **col4**

```
 col3
```

So col4 change from row2 -> row1, col3. And cal3 get from row1 -> row2, col4. Just on mobile.
**Note: This is to be applied just on *mobile/small screen*. For the display is fine for midle and large screen.**

Comment: what about using an offset for the small screen? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: Hey, thank's for your comment. I just added the code. to my post. The Offset just "Move columns to the right". But i want to move it from top to down and just on mobile screen!

Comment: My bad I mean push / pull http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: Hey i've already tried that. It's not working at all. Don't know why!

Comment: Then maybe you should research if you've got the push/pull syntax correct. You make it sound like it had no affect on the page -- do more learning and research. Also, it's rather rude to end every single sentence you write with `!` even your profile page says "Master of Infomatics!" I hope you don't walk around all day yelling at everyone ...

Comment: Here is a bit play ground. I was able to get column 3 to go down. The only thing pending is for column 4 to go up. http://jsfiddle.net/oe3un4so/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help guys. Since swapping looks difficult, i decided to move col3 under column col4. So no swapping anymore. Just bringing the position of col3 under col4 on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use a flex container for your divs all in the same div, you might try using the [order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) in a media query for smaller screens. It lets you select the order of elements. I've done a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kizzy/f02d0xbm/3/).

Here's the CSS I used.

```
.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #col1 {order: 1;}
  #col2 {order: 2;}
  #col3 {order: 4;}
  #col4 {order: 3;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this using Bootstrap grid classes alone. The easiest way to do it without touching JavaScript would be to bring all the columns into the same parent container and add a copy of the third column that you toggle between:

```
<div class="row1">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4" id="col1">#1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4" id="col2">#2</div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4" id="col3a">#3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12" id="col4">#4</div>
    <div class="hidden visible-xs-block col-xs-12" id="col3b">#3</div>
</div>
```

You could probably do it with the fourth column instead, if the content makes it easier.

Comment: You are right. Look like swapping column in rows is not possible with bootstrap. So i've decided just to move col3 under col4 on mobile display! I've tried with col-md-push-12 but not positive result!